# Mapping a network drive using the WIX Toolset

Tags: wix

I'm making a new installers for the software I'm developing and we are replacing BitRock and using the WiX Toolset instead. While the installer itself was fairly easy to create some of the behaviors we had in the BitRock installer have been harder to translate to WiX.

A little background on the System being developed. It is a Windows client and Linux server with the server generating files that the client user needs to be able to access. The way we do this is by mapping a network drive on the windows machine. The old BitRock installer we used did make an attempt to map this drive at install and would let the user know if it was unable to map the drive so they could go map it manually. I would like to include this behavior in the WiX based installer if possible. Also while handy the client does not need the network drive mapped to function properly.

I know how to create the dialogs and properties needed in WiX to get the path of the network drive into the installer but I can't find anything that actually sets up the mapping. My question is as follows;

Can WiX map a network drive itself or is it something that needs to be done in a CustomAction?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/util/fileshare.html file share element that is part of the util extention.

[How to use Util Extention](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/howtos/general/extension_usage_introduction.html)

Comment: I'm not sure that this would work for me. The FileShare says that it makes the file share out of a components directory. What I'm looking for is a way to  map another computers share as a drive on the machine running the installer.